# How to copy all the pixels in a circle on a BITMAP image and paste to another spot on the image?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to copy an area (circle) on an image to another part of the image. (Like shown below)

[image: Example Image]

Something similar is the `CopyRect` procedure. The only difference is the shape.

Comment: I wonder how this question might be too broad :)

Comment: @MBo Certainly close reason is way off; and other close reasons would also be dubious. This is possibly a negative side-effect of OP having scattered so many tags at the question.

Answer (score 10):

- Create clipping region (CreateEllipticRgn here, CombineRgn for more complex figures)
- Select it ([SelectClipRgn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162955(v=vs.85).aspx)) in destination device context (Canvas.handle).
- Copy rectangle containing needed fragment. Parts outside clip region remain the same.
- Remove clipping region